# Error opening programs with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu.
If I type this into the terminal:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('firefox')
```

This is returned:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xb76c080c>
>>> nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 55
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 56
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 59
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 58
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
```

It doesn't return back to the python terminal: `>>>`

I am new to python on linux -- can anyone show me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:

For anyone interested in fixing this, I solved the immediate issue this way:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
Popen('firefox',stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: python's [`webbrowswer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module might be of interest to you ...

Comment: That is very cool I must say! However it is unrelated. I am merely trying to get it to open a variable program and firefox came off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way to open a browser.  Maybe try this instead:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

By the way, it has returned back to your python terminal, I can see that in the output.  There has been some chatter on stdout or stderr from the process, which may have overwritten the `>>> prompt`, but if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times you will probably find you're still at the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Comment: @phileaton -- The "error" looks like it's firefox unique.  It might be a problem that the gui program doesn't know how to communicate with the window manager or something ...

Comment: It is not an error, it is just warning chatters from the subprocess which you wouldn't normally see if you start firefox from a GUI.

Comment: Interesting. I modified the code and the error went away. This is how I modified it:   subprocess.Popen('firefox',stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

Comment: You will block up the pipes and cause it to hang, eventually, this way (the pipes have a limited buffer).  It is better to redirect them to `os.devnull` if you don't want to see that chatter.